# Replace a string in parameter with a variable

Tags: dominotogo

I think I'm making this harder than what it is, but I can't figure out how to use a variable instead of hard coding the string in the call below. I want to replace "John Doe" with my firstName variable...

```
var firstName = "John Doe";
db.downloadDocumentsBySelection('SELECT Form="People" & FirstName="John Doe"', function(success, param)
```

I've tried the following but I get an error: NotesDatabase: httpClient error

```
var firstName = "John Doe";
db.downloadDocumentsBySelection('SELECT Form="People" & FirstName= "+firstName+"', function(success, param)
```

I'm not sure if I need to escape the quotes? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var firstName = "John Doe";
db.downloadDocumentsBySelection('SELECT Form="People" & FirstName= "'+firstName+'"', function(success, param)
```

Note the combination of " and ' and after FirstName.